# Using www and non-www domain with one SSL certificate

Tags: apache

I want to use one SSL certificate for www and for non-www traffic.
Therefore, I want to redirect all traffic from www to non-www.
(Certificate is for non-www).

The following Rule redirect from non-www to www. But I need the oposite. https://www.example.com to https://example.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the domain name this should  work:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`